# TCHART with Delphi - cannot have bar show amount and a text description

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a Delphi Berlin program showing a bar chart, and I want a label above each bar showing the numeric value, and another label below the bar showing a description, like a day of the week. I can get both if I use 2 buttons, showing one or the other,  but is there a way to show 2 labels on a bar chart, one above the bar, one below? In this program, button2 shows a label above and an axis below, but it is showing the same info twice for each bar.

I tried to ask this in a previous post, but there was not enough space in a reply to add enough details.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    i : integer;
begin   
    chart1.series[0].clear;
        for i := 1 to 4  do
             chart1.series[0].add(100+5*i,'',clred);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    i : integer;
begin
    chart1.series[0].clear;
    day[1] := 'Sun';
    day[2] := 'Mon';
    day[3] := 'Tues';
    day[4] := 'Wed';
    for i := 1 to 4  do
        chart1.series[0].add(100+5*i,day[i],clred);
end;
```

Comment: Your previous question asked *Remove text over each bar*, and now you're posting a question about how to put it back? And please at least make an effort to properly format your code. If you're not sure how, click the *?* button at the top right corner of the text area for some instructions.

Comment: "*...but there was not enough space in a reply to add enough details...*" You do know that you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41559446/edit) your posts, don't you?  Just use the *edit* button beneath the tags to open the editor.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Ken & Tom. Initially, the displayed labels contained random number, and for reasons unknown it fixed itself. I am glad to see it displaying the value I added to each series, and the next poster provided the solution. How do I mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the series marks is set as `smsLabelOrValue` and the axis label style is set to `talAuto`; this will show the point label if present or the point value if no label is present for that point.

To change that behaviour you can change these properties:

- Series marks style:

  ```
  Chart1.Series[0].Marks.Style:=smsValue;
  ```

  Possible values:

  ```
  smsValue,             { 1234 }
  smsPercent,           { 12 % }
  smsLabel,             { Cars } // If label is empty, no mark will be displayed
  smsLabelPercent,      { Cars 12 % }
  smsLabelValue,        { Cars 1234 }
  smsLegend,            { (Legend.Style) }
  smsPercentTotal,      { 12 % of 1234 }
  smsLabelPercentTotal, { Cars 12 % of 1234 }
  smsXValue,            { 1..2..3.. or 21/6/2014 }
  smsXY,                { 123 456 }
  smsSeriesTitle,       { Series1 }
  smsPointIndex,        { 1..2..3... }
  smsPercentRelative,   { 100%..90%..120%... }
  smsLabelPercentValue, { Cars 12 % 1234 }
  smsLabelOrValue
  ```
- Axis label style:

  ```
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelStyle:=talValue; //talAuto, talNone, talValue, talMark, talText, talPointValue
  ```

In your case, adding this to your code in Button2Click gives the desired result:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Marks.Style:=smsValue;
```

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0):

Yeray's answer is the solution. Repeated here: Chart1.Series[0].Marks.Style:=smsValue;

Comment: Instead of repeating the correct answer, [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.

Comment: From above link: *Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question*.